# Handling different data types in a node-based interpreter

Tags: java

I am making a simple node-base interpreter in java. The interpreter supports binary operations between Integer, Double, String, and some other object types. Some examples include addition between integer and double and concatenating two strings.

Here is the basic structure of the nodes:

```
public abstract class Node {
  public LiteralNode execute ();
}
```

```
public abstract class LiteralNode extends Node {
  public Object getValue();
}
```

```
public class IntegerNode extends LiteralNode {
  private Integer value;
  
  public IntegerNode(Integer val) {
    value = val;
  }

  public Integer getValue() { return value; }

  public LiteralNode execute() { return this; }  
  ...
}
```

`DoubleNode` and `StringNode` etc. follow the same structure as `IntegerNode`, except with different value types.

An example operation node:

```
public class AdditionNode extends Node {
  public Node left, right;

  public LiteralNode execute() {
    LiteralNode lresult = left.execute();
    LiteralNode rresult = right.execute();
    
    // This does not work. Need some kind of casting
    return Operations.add(lresult, rresult);
  }
}
```

```
public final class Operations {
  public static LiteralNode add(IntegerNode e1, IntegerNode e2) {
    return new LiteralNode(e1.getValue() + e2.getValue());
  }
  public static LiteralNode add(StringNode e1, IntegerNode e2) {
    // Give some error
    return null;
  }
  ... Double+Integer, etc.

  // No other appropriate overloaded method is found. Use the most general one.
  public static LiteralNode add(LiteralNode e1, LiteralNode e2) {
    // Error: Unknown operands
    return null;
  }
}
```

Other operation nodes do similar things.

Now, the part I'm stuck on is dealing with the type of values held in `lresult` and `rresult`. I want to do, for example, if both are `IntegerNode` then add and return new `LiteralNode`, or if one is `StringNode` and another is `DoubleNode`, give an error.

If I simply call the overloaded method on the two results, I get error and null since the two results are stored as `LiteralNode` instead of a specific sub-class. Yet I can't know their type beforehand so I have to either check `instanceof` or have some kind of label attribute. The problem is that I have several custom classes that could also be an operand, so checking every combination and then cast would make the code super messy.

I tried using generics, but ended up with the same problem due to type erasure. I also tried to use the visitor pattern to process the nodes instead of using the overloaded method, but I couldn't figure out a way to make it work, since the two nodes need to be processed together.

How should I deal with this issue?

Please tell me if you need more details. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know if it is the best approach but you could try using a try/catch block in Operations class. One only add method receiving two LiteralNode, you get the value and perform the addition or whatever inside a try catch. If they can be added you have a result, if not, you enter in the catch block and return whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that it has no proper basis. But it's luckily solvable. You can declare and implement all operations as methods for this `abstract class`, (it could easily be an interface as well) including

- `add`
- `subtract`
- etc.

For example `add` would be a method that gets two `Node` parameters and returns a `Node` parameter. Inside the method you could check for the operands, like

```
public Node add(Node a, Node b) {
    if ((a.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("SomeClassName")) && (b.getClass().getSimpleName.equals("SomeClassName2"))) {
         //implement the actual operation
    }
    //...
}
```

Since you repeat these criteria in different methods, it would also make sense to make an abstraction for the criterias so the logical operands would be simplified. `Node` is not necessarily an `abstract` class, but even if it is, I would implement the operations at its level and only override it in subclasses if there is some benefit to it. This will reduce some of the mess you perceive.